# IE11 : Select dropdown is infinetly scrolling (looping)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, responsive-design

Am using a select input within my angular app and which i run withing my tablet (Windows).

My html is this :

```
<select name="vendorSelect"  class="col-xs-12 " id="vendorSelect" [(ngModel)]="currentVendor">
                      <option  [hidden]="true" disabled [value]="selectUndefinedOptionValue" ></option> 
        <option *ngFor="let vendor of listVendor" [ngValue]="vendor">
                {{vendor.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

When running , my select-dropdown is behaving in two ways :

1. **Mouse Click :** dropdown opens , shows options while scroling until the end of the list **(OK)**
2. **Finger Touch :** dropdown opens , appearence different (inspired from native mobile appearenece) , shows options while scrolling

**+** *when reaching the end of the list :* the scroll got in the top again and **re-display** the options from the beginning ( it looks like infinite list / looping 
(but in facts it re-start the list from its beginning)  **(KO)**

-> this issue is only with **IE** ,

**any solutions to prevent this looping scroll ?**